# how to send the Notifications to multiple checked values in android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Hi in the below I am creating group for that I am passing the groupname with no.of the friends in that group.
Now My question is `friendAdapter.getCheckedItems()` using this method I am getting the only checked values.Now,I want to send the Notification to only checked friends in the group message should be groupname with username.

**java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.group_list_screen);

        Button create=(Button)findViewById(R.id.create);


        friendAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this); 



        create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "unchecked" })
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String groupname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nick");

                            try {


                                imService=Login.imService;

                                String result1 = imService.CreateGroup(groupname,imService.getUsername(),friendAdapter.getCheckedItems());



                                System.out.println(result1);
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Created Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

**imService.CreateGroup().java**

```
public String CreateGroup(String groupname,String username,
            ArrayList<FriendInfo> result) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {
        this.groupname=groupname;       
         List<String> usersName = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) { 
                 usersName.add(result.get(i).userName); 

            }
                String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.groupname,"UTF-8") +
                        "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&friendUserName=" +usersName.toString().replaceAll(" ","")+        
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);      


    }
```

**sendmessage()**

```
public void sendmessage(FriendInfo[] result)
    {


        if (result != null) 
        {
            NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (result.length > 0)
            {                   
                String tmp = new String();
                for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    tmp = tmp.concat(result[j].userName).concat(",");           
                }
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stat_sample)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist));
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, 
                        getText(R.string.new_friend_request_exist),
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                String groupname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nick");
                Intent i = new Intent(this, FriendList.class);
                i.putExtra(FriendInfo.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);                

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        i, 0);

                mBuilder.setContentText("You have new Group request"+groupname);


                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


                NM.notify(R.string.new_group_request_exist, mBuilder.build());          
            }
            else
            {

                NM.cancel(R.string.new_group_request_exist);            
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: where is your send notification code?

Comment: that is my question how to send the multiple user

Comment: ok are you tried to send single user?

Comment: first of all how to access the only checked values using this method &friendUserName=[user3,user1,user2]

Comment: see my send notification code

Answer (score 0):

"Group" messages are sent to individuals, not "groups" of individuals. In your messaging protocol, you may (and should) include the list of group participants (for the user and for "reply" purposes).

But if you are trying to "send to a group" then the messaging service you are using needs to support that. Also, "GroupNames" are usually not supported in messaging protocols - names are a convenience for the user, not the other group members.

You do not specify how you are sending the message - SMS, chat, etc.

If you want to know which users are "checked" you simply need to iterate over the adapter (it should contain all of the data) or maintain a list as the items are checked.

EDIT:

Your `sendMessage` method is notifying the device for the user - it does not send "notifications" to other devices. You need to use SMS, Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), Amazon Notifications or some other means to "send" a message (then the device and/or app will notify when it is received).

Comment: see my sendmessage method can you give me some example

Comment: messaing service only I am using

Comment: See my edit. You are not "notifying" another device, only the device the user is using...

Comment: using service we can send to particular users ?

Comment: An "Android Service" runs on the device. "Google Play Services" is completely different...